# Why is this an effective captcha?

Tags: meaning, translation, katakana

I want to sign up to this website that has an English version, but unfortunately, the captcha for it is Japanese.  I can't read Japanese and no online translator seems to be able to make sense of the 2nd line. Here it is:

> 表示されている数式を計算して、半角数字で答えを入力してください:  必須（半角数字）

> ろクタスナナは

[image]

Why is this an effective captcha?

I'd also like to know the meaning, the translation, and why no translator seems to be able to translate that last word.

Thanks.

Comment: It is an effective captcha just because you weren't able to read; they successfully shut out efforts of automatic recognition. Except they forgot to make an English version...

Answer (score 1):

It shows ”ろく たす なな“.
To obfuscate sentence, It use combination of HIRAGANA and KATAKANA.

6+7

Comment: OK but what does the first line say?

Comment: @ConsultingNewb it says "Solve the following arithmetic problem and submit your answer in half-width characters."